# TYPO3 groupedFor from crdate

Tags: controller, typo3, extbase

i just want to know how it is possible to get the month and the year from an extbase article in TYPO3. I have th crdate column. Is it possible to get the two values that i want from this field? I added this

Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php

```
return [
  \Vendor\Name\Domain\Model\Item::class => [
    'tableName' => 'TABLE',
    'properties' => [
        'cruserId' => [
            'fieldName' => 'cruser_id'
        ],
        'year' => [
            'fieldName' => 'crdate'
        ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Then in the Model

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected string $year = '';

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getYear(): string
{
    return date('F', (int)$this->getCrdate());
}

/**
 * @param string $month
 */
public function setYear(string $year): void
{
    $this->year = $year;
}
```

I see the new value in the f:debug and the crdate is now empty. But the year now have the value from the crdate field. How can i get the right value?

**EDIT:**

I've tried following without success:

Model:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $crdate;

/**
 * Get year of crdate
 *
 * @return false|string
 */
public function getYearOfCrdate()
{
    return $this->crdate->format('Y');
}

/**
 * Get month of crdate
 *
 * @return false|string
 */
public function getMonthOfCrdate()
{
    return $this->crdate->format('m');
}
```

TCA:

```
'columns' => [
   'crdate' => [
        'label' => 'crdate',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
            'eval' => 'datetime',
        ]
    ],
```

And removed my other code

Partial:

```
<f:groupedFor each="{articles}" as="item" groupBy="getYearOfCrdate" groupKey="year">
    <f:for each="{item}" as="article" key="title">
      Test
    </f:for>
</f:groupedFor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make that work you need the following steps:

1. Add a TCA configuration for crdate

Even though the field `crdate` is already defined in the section `ctrl` of the TCA the following code is **additionally** required because extbase needs this to correctly map the field. The `ctrl` information is used in the backend to fill this field when creating the record.

```php
'crdate' => [
            'label' => 'crdate',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'eval' => 'datetime',
            ]
        ],
```

2. Instead of using a year property add the following in the model

```php
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $crdate;

    /**
     * Get year of crdate
     *
     * @return false|string
     */
    public function getYearOfCrdate()
    {
        return $this->crdate->format('Y');
    }
```

3. use this getter in the groupedfor ViewHelper

```html
<f:groupedFor each="{articles}" as="item" groupBy="yearOfCrdate" groupKey="year">
```

---

code is taken from https://github.com/georgringer/news/

Comment: Thank you. Right now i have the crdate in the ctrl array and in columsn. Should i remove the part in the ctrl array?

Comment: Using a getter in fluid should leave away the "get" and only note the property: <f:groupedFor each="{articles}" as="item" groupBy="yearOfCrdate" groupKey="year">

Comment: yes you need both. I updated the answer and also added the HTML example. thx for that